Passing list of notes with SwiftData to subviews
I am building a SwiftUI application using SwiftData. I have a list of Note objects that I need to display in different subviews grouped by year, month, and day. However, I'm running into issues passing the list of notes to these subviews and ensuring they update correctly when the data changes.
struct MainView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    
    @Query private var notesList: [Note]
    @State private var notes = [Note]()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            if !notes.isEmpty{
                DaySectionView(notes: $notes)
            }else{
                ContentUnavailableView{
                    Label("No Notes", systemImage: "note.text")
                        .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: notesList, initial: true){
            notes = notesList
        }
    }
}

struct DaySectionView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @Binding var notes: [Note]
    @State private var remainingNotes = [Note]()
       
    var body: some View {
        let firstNoteDay = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: notes.first!.date).day ?? 0
        let notesForSameDay = notes.filter {
            Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: $0.date).day == firstNoteDay
        }

        ForEach(notesForSameDay, id: \.self){ note in
            NavigationLink{
                NoteDetailsView(note: .constant(note))
            }label: {
                NoteCardView(note: note)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: notes, initial: true){
            guard let firstNote = notes.first else { return }
            remainingNotes = notes.filter {
                Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: $0.date).day != firstNoteDay
            }
         }
        if !remainingNotes.isEmpty {
            DaySectionView(notes: $remainingNotes)
        }
    }
}

// NoteDetailsView
    @Binding var note: Note

// NoteCardView
    var note: Note

I tried to use @Bindable, but doesn't work with me.
All models working very well.

You don’t need to use Binding/Bindable between MainView and DaySectionView

Binding is for value types, get rid of that second and third State and use Bindable on the exact note you are editing. Query is a one-way connection that is why there isn’t any binding. Constant should never used outside of preview.
